# Way to toggle Mesh 3d plots in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly-python

I'm trying to make a mesh 3d plot in python using plotly. The plot is working fine but as I have read Mesh 3d plots doesn't have legend support. So there's no way I'm able to toggle the mesh 3d plot.

Is there any way I can make this functionality of toggling the mesh 3d plot in python?

Comment: I think the feature was added [issue link](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2642), but not sure how to actually add a legend to a mesh graph